# Multiplication of 3D matrix by 2D matrix in Matlab without using loops

Tags: matrices, matlab, products

Want to multiply a $3D$ matrix $A$ of size $n$ x $m$ x $p$, ($n$: number of raws, $m$: number of columns and $p$: number of slices), by a 2D matrix $B$ of size $m$ x 1 x $p$. The results as shown in the figure below is a matrix $C$ of size $n$ x 1 x $p$. How to perform this on Matlab without using loops ?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10161-3d-matrix-multiplication

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is the good place for asking such question.
I suppose that you want to compute the output matrix $\mathbf{C}$ as

```
C(:,:,p)=A(:,:,p)*B(:,:,p)
```

using the matrix product.
You can easily do this using implicit broadcasting

```
C = sum(A.*permute(B,[2,1,3]),2)
```